# $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Hey so I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding this one.

> $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}$
>
> 1) $x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}$ * $(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-3x}}{x-\sqrt{x^2-3x}})$
>
> 2) $\frac{x^2-(x^2-3x)}{x-\sqrt{x^2-3x}}$
>
> 3) $\frac{3x}{x-\sqrt{x^2(1-\frac{3}{x}})}$
>
> 4) $\frac{3x}{x-\sqrt{x^2}*\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}}}$
>
> 5) $\frac{3x}{x-x(\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}})}$
>
> 6) $\frac{3}{1-(\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}})}$

Now I would just take the limit, it would result in $\frac{3}{1-1}$ which would be undefined. For some reason, the $x$ in the denominator of step 5 should turn into $-(-x)$ which in turn would be positive and therefore be $\frac{3}{1+\sqrt{1=\frac{3}{x}}}$ which would equal $\frac{3}{2}$.

I really don't get it. Apparently the $-\infty$ would mean that $\sqrt{x^2}$ = $-x$. We didn't even evaluate the limit yet.. how does that turn into $-x$, just because we know the limit is negative does not mean we evaluated it yet..., why not simplify until there is no more simplification to be done, which is what I did in my steps, which would evaluate to undefined?

Would love some help, thanks!

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ has two solutions for $x$: $\pm x$; if $x<0$ the only solution is $-x$.

Comment: So based on that we know that $x$ is negative before we even evaluate the limit, we just take $-x$? If so, do we replace $x$ by $-\infty$ or by  $\infty$ after we get $\sqrt{x^2}$ = $-x$

Comment: You take $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}$. If this limit exists and equals $a$, is means that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x<M$, we have $|x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}-a|<\epsilon$. Since this holds for all $x<M$, we can assume without loss of generality that $M<0$, for if this holds for an $M\geq0$, it certainly holds for any negative $M$.

Comment: You might do better with $lim_{y\to \infty} \sqrt{y^2+3y}-y$ by using $y=-x$. Your approach then leads to $\frac{3}{2}$ without worrying about the ambiguity of the square root.

Comment: Just test it for a few values of $x$ (approaching $-\infty$)! When $x=-10$ you have $x^2=100$. So $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{100}=10=-x$. When $x=-100$ you have $x^2=10000$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{10000}=100=-x$. Do you see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed that, for $x<0$, $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$, so when you pull $x^2$ outside the square root it must become $-x$ and not $x$. We can assume $x<0$ because we're doing a limit for $x\to-\infty$, so restricting the function to an interval of the form $(-\infty,a)$, for any $a$, is possible and doesn't affect the limit.

You avoid most problem of this kind if you switch to positive infinity ($x=-y$) or to “positive $0$” ($x=-1/t$). With the latter method, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}\,\bigr)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(-\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{3}{t}}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+3t}-1}{t}
$$
which should be much easier (either as a derivative or using the usual technique with the conjugate). Here we can simplify $\sqrt{t^2}=t$ because we're working in a right neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases, to avoid confusion with signs, I often suggest, at least as a check, to take $y=-x \to \infty$ and then

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}=\lim_{y\to \infty} -y+\sqrt{y^2+3y}$$

and from here we can proceed as usual.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$

$y:=-x$ , and consider $\lim y \rightarrow + \infty.$

$\sqrt{y^2+3y}-y= \dfrac{(y^2+3y)-y^2}{\sqrt{y^2+3y}+y}=$

$\dfrac{3y}{\sqrt{y^2+3y}+y}= \dfrac{3y}{y(\sqrt{1+3/y}+1)}$

$=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1+3/y}+1}.$

Take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

We are near $-\infty$, so $x<0$ and $|x|=-x$.

thus

$$x+\sqrt{x^2-3x}=x+\sqrt{x^2(1-\frac 3x)}$$

$$=x+|x|\sqrt{1-\frac 3x}$$
$$=x(1-\sqrt{1-\frac 3x})$$
$$=x\frac{\frac 3x}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac 3x}}$$

the limit is $\frac 32$.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Taylor's expansion*:

When x approches $-\infty$:

$x + \sqrt{x^2-3x} = x - x(1 - \frac{3}{2x}+\text{o}(x)) = x - x + \frac{3}{2}+\text{o}(1) \rightarrow \frac{3}{2}$.

So, yeah

$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}x + \sqrt{x^2-3x} =\frac{3}{2}.
\end{align}
$